# Google Analytics Goal funnel not working

Tags: google-analytics, goals, goal-tracking

I have been a user of Google Analytics for over 2 years and like to think I am adept at using it but this issue has really thrown me.

I have a Goal set up which appears to be working on first looking at the overview. It gives me 42 Goal Conversions, but when I go in to look at the Goal Funnel Visualization it states 0 visitors finished.

What is happening here? Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A goal will be registered if it is hit no matter how you get there.  With a funnel required steps must be hit and in the correct order otherwise they will not register as finished.

Comment: +1. Funnel Visualizations do not define how Goals are executed, and the 'Steps' in them are only used in the funnel, and do not relate to whether Goals get counted. This means the funnel is not properly configured.

Comment: There is only one funnel step so "Initial Form" (required) and "Form Completed Thankyou". Still can't see why it doesn't work. Very confusing. It is set up correctly as far as I can see.